# batch file/ bash scripts validator

Tags: bash, batch-file

Is there any online batch file/ bash scripts validator? Let you drop the code in the textarea and check syntax errors? Or upload a file for validation.

Comment: I found [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/). Although the question was closed as off-topic, and it's pretty old, an answer would be nice when others will come across this question.

Answer (score 6):

I doubt it, since you can just do `bash -n yourscript.sh`

Searching, I couldn't find one either. Plenty of hits on using `-n` though...